# Make div stick to bottom of parent

Tags: html, css

I made a simple CSS only bar chart, but all bars start from the top.

```css
.wrap {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.barchart {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 0.2px;
}

.barchart.column {
  width: 11px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  font-size: xx-small;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="barchart column" style="background: #666; height: 
    50px">5</div>
  <div class="barchart column" style="background: #666; height: 
    70px">7</div>
</div>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jL68sa0h/

I already tried to set position: relative for parent div and position: absolute; for the bars and it didn't work..

How is possible to make the bars stick to bottom using only CSS?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `flex-flow: wrap-reverse;` or `align-items: flex-end;`

```
.wrap {
      display : flex;
      flex-flow: wrap-reverse;
}
```

solution:

```css
.wrap {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display : flex;
  flex-flow: wrap-reverse;
  height:100vh;
}

.barchart {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 0.2px;
}

.barchart.column {
  width: 11px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  font-size: xx-small;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<div class="barchart column" style="background: #666; height: 50px">5</div>
<div class="barchart column" style="background: #666; height: 70px">7</div>
<div class="barchart column" style="background: #666; height: 90px">9</div>
<div class="barchart column" style="background: #666; height: 110px">11</div>
<div class="barchart column" style="background: #666; height: 130px">13</div>
<div class="barchart column" style="background: #666; height: 80px">8</div>
<div class="barchart column" style="background: #666; height: 100px">10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any difference between vertical-align and flex? Maybe in browser support or something like that? Thanks!

Comment: The vertical-align property in CSS controls how elements set next to each other on a line are lined up. [https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/v/vertical-align/](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/v/vertical-align/)

Answer (score 1):

Add `vertical-align:bottom;` to your .`barchart` class:

```css
.wrap {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.barchart {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 0.2px;
  vertical-align:bottom;
}

.barchart.column {
  width: 11px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  font-size: xx-small;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="barchart column" style="background: #666; height: 
    50px">5</div>
  <div class="barchart column" style="background: #666; height: 
    70px">7</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using flexbox? You can just make you're wrapper a flexbox and then align the items to flex-end:

```
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```